# How to get RGB values using Java

Tags: java, pixel

I'm trying to get the pixels in RGB format of an image. I have the following code:

```
public void writeColorImageValueToFile(BufferedImage in, String fileName)   
    {   
    int width = in.getWidth();   
    int height = in.getHeight();   

    try   
    {   
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName + ".txt");   
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);   

        int [] data = new int[width * height];      
        in.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, data, 0, width);   

        for(int i = 0; i < (height * width); i++)   
        {                        
            out.write(((data[i] >> 16) & 0xff) + ", ");    
            out.write(((data[i] >> 8) & 0xff) + ", ");   
            out.write((data[i] & 0xff) + "\n");   
        }   

        out.close();   
    } catch (Exception e)   
    {   
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());   
    }   
}
```

I created an image in photoshop and I filled it with the color RGB(86, 136, 152), however I got from my java method the value of RGB(44, 139, 154).

I load the image using:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("blue.jpg"))
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you saving the file from photoshop? (It's possible that the colors are being mapped.) How are you reading the file into a BufferedImage?

Comment: @Ted Using the traditional method (File Menu - Save as JPG)

Comment: You might want to look at endianness, perhaps

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but you should be aware that jpg image format uses lossy compression.

Comment: Side note: avoid performing expensive calculations which are expected to not change in the condition part of a for-loop, as this will be evaluated for every loop iteration.  In this case "height * width" in for(int i = 0; i < (height * width); i++).

Comment: @JimN agreed, this looks like the .jpg compression at work.

Comment: I agree. I've seen this kind of thing in my own work, which is why I asked how it was saved. @Eric - Try saving as png instead.

Comment: It's definitely the JPEG's lossy compression...

Answer (score -1):

try save your image to PNG format and try again!

Comment: I believe this is a comment, no?